# Does fragile base class issue exist in Go?

Tags: oop, inheritance, go, composition

Despite using composition over inheritance?

If so, is there any solution for it at the language level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As VonC wrote, but I'd like to point out something.

The [fragile base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem is often blamed on [virtual methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) (*dynamic dispatch of methods* – this means if methods can be overridden, the actual implementation that has to be called in case of such an overridden method can only be decided at runtime).

Why is this a problem? You have a class, you add some methods to it, and if `MethodA()` calls `MethodB()`, you can't have any guarantee that the `MethodB()` you wrote will be called and not some other method of a subclass that overrides your `MethodB()`.

In Go there is [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), but there is no [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). If you embed a type in a struct, all the methods of the embedded type get *promoted* and will be in the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the wrapper struct type. But you can't "override" the promoted methods. Sure, you can add your own method with the same name, and calling a method by that name on the wrapper struct will invoke your method, but if this method is called from the embedded type, that will not be dispatched to your method, it will still call the "original" method that was defined to the embedded type.

So because of this, I'd say the fragile base class problem is only present in a quite mitigated form in Go.

### Example

#### Demonstrating the problem in Java

Let's see an example. First in Java, because Java "suffers" from this kind of problem. Let's create a simple `Counter` class and a `MyCounter` subclass:

```
class Counter {
    int value;

    void inc() {
        value++;
    }

    void incBy(int n) {
        value += n;
    }
}

class MyCounter extends Counter {
    void inc() {
        incBy(1);
    }
}
```

Instantiating and using `MyCounter`:

```
MyCounter m = new MyCounter();
m.inc();
System.out.println(m.value);
m.incBy(2);
System.out.println(m.value);
```

The output is as expected:

```
1
3
```

So far so good. Now if the base class, `Counter.incBy()` would be changed to this:

```
void incBy(int n) {
    for (; n > 0; n--) {
        inc();
    }
}
```

The base class `Counter` still remains flawless and operational. But the `MyCounter` becomes malfunctioning: `MyCounter.inc()` calls `Counter.incBy()`, which calls `inc()` but due to dynamic dispatch, it will call `MyCounter.inc()`... yes... endless loop. Stack overflow error.

#### Demonstrating the *lack* of the problem in Go

Now let's see the same example, this time written in Go:

```
type Counter struct {
    value int
}

func (c *Counter) Inc() {
    c.value++
}

func (c *Counter) IncBy(n int) {
    c.value += n
}

type MyCounter struct {
    Counter
}

func (m *MyCounter) Inc() {
    m.IncBy(1)
}
```

Testing it:

```
m := &MyCounter{}
m.Inc()
fmt.Println(m.value)
m.IncBy(2)
fmt.Println(m.value)
```

Output is as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zKqIa9DrOG)):

```
1
3
```

Now let's change `Counter.Inc()`  the same way we did in the Java example:

```
func (c *Counter) IncBy(n int) {
    for ; n > 0; n-- {
        c.Inc()
    }
}
```

It runs perfectly, the output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FnI7aMdS69).

What happens here is that `MyCounter.Inc()` will call `Counter.IncBy()` which will call `Inc()`, but this `Inc()` will be `Counter.Inc()`, so no endless loop here. `Counter` doesn't even know about `MyCounter`, it does not have any reference to the embedder `MyCounter` value.

Comment: Excellent explanation. +1 for the examples.

Comment: +1 for pointing out virtual methods as one of the root causes.  In fact, I wonder if virtual methods are *thee* root cause of the Fragile Base Class problem.  If you were not allowed to override a method with implementation, would the problem even exist?

Answer (score 2):

The [Fragile base class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem is when a seemingly safe modifications to a base class, when inherited by the derived classes, may cause the derived classes to malfunction.

As mentioned [in this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lets-go-object-oriented-programming-in-golang--cms-26540):

> For all intents and purposes, composition by e[mbedding an anonymous type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) is equivalent to implementation inheritance. An embedded struct is just as fragile as a base class.

Comment: While the quotation is correct, I don't fully agree with it. See my reasoning in my answer.