# How can I organise this Go code that redefines methods from an embedded type to be less redundant and more maintainable?

Tags: inheritance, go, methods, embedding, organization

I have [some example code](https://play.golang.org/p/oRBB1xs_Sn) in which I declare a type `foo` with some methods which call each other (say: `foo.get`, which is called by `foo.double` and `foo.toString`).

I have another type, `bar`, which embeds `foo` and redefines `get`.  I am forced to redefine `double` and `toString` on `bar`, so they can see `bar.get` (rather than only `foo.get`), but the body of these functions is basically identical to the original.

Is there a better way to organise this code, to avoid the redundancy while still having `bar` fulfill the same interfaces as `foo`?

Notes:

- The code as organised above *works* fine; it's just difficult to maintain because when I go to redefine a method originally declared on `foo` on an type that embeds `foo` I have to check carefully to see which other methods on `foo` call it, and make sure to redefine all of those too.  It has proven to be very easy to accidentally miss one.
- In the real project on which this is based there are nearly a dozen types which embed '`foo`', and a similar number of inter-connected methods on each type.
- I could add an interface-valued member to foo containing a pointer to the outermost enclosing struct that embeds it, and have `foo.double` call `f.outermost.get()` instead of `f.get()`, but this seems a little wasteful and would mean that zero values of `foo` were not valid.  (Plus it is only possible if the embedded type is a struct.)

Answer (score 3):

In Go there is [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), but there is no [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). If you embed a type in a struct, all the methods of the embedded type get promoted and will be in the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the wrapper struct type. But you can't "override" the promoted methods. Sure, you can add your own method with the same name, and calling a method by that name on the wrapper struct will invoke your method, but if this method is called from the embedded type, that will not be dispatched to your method, it will still call the "original" method that was defined to the embedded type.

Read more about this here: [Does fragile base class issue exist in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819033/does-fragile-base-class-issue-exist-in-go/41827686#41827686) and here: [Go embedded struct call child method instead parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method/29390981#29390981).

It looks like you only want to "inherit" the `double()` and `toString()` methods (which should be called `String()` in Go), but not the `get()` method as its implementation changes from type-to-type.

So basically you should refactor a little. Your `foo` type should have / get a value that provides the `get()` method. You can capture this with a `getter` interface:

```
type getter interface {
    get() int
}
```

And the `foo` implementation:

```
type foo struct {
    g getter
}

func (f foo) double() int {
    return f.g.get() * 2
}

func (f foo) toString() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", f.g.get())
}
```

And a `bar` type which embeds `foo`, and only provides the "missing" `get()`:

```
type bar struct {
    foo
}

func (b bar) get() int {
    return 69
}
```

Usage example:

```
b := bar{}
b.foo = foo{g: b}
fmt.Println(b.double())
fmt.Println(b.toString())
```

Output is as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZvpnNdEYEi)):

```
138
69
```

#### With a simple function value

Using the above `getter` interface is nice, as it provides flexibility in the future, should you need to add other methods to it.

If this is not the case and all you need is a single function, you may leave out the interface and just use a function value.

This is how it could look like:

```
type foo struct {
    get func() int
}

func (f foo) double() int {
    return f.get() * 2
}

func (f foo) toString() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", f.get())
}

type bar struct {
    foo
}

func (b bar) get() int {
    return 69
}
```

And using it:

```
b := bar{}
b.foo = foo{get: b.get}
fmt.Println(b.double())
fmt.Println(b.toString())
```

Output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7f5OVjhwWw).

Note that while we used the `bar.get()` method (`b.get` [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)), it is not a requirement that `get()` should be a method. It can be an ordinary function value, or even a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals), such as:

```
b := bar{foo: foo{get: func() int { return 69 }}}
fmt.Println(b.double())
fmt.Println(b.toString())
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-qHV3HmmlC).

Comment: Yes: I'd like my base class to be a little more fragile…

Comment: I like this approach; it definitely makes the code easier to maintain.  It's a pity that it comes at the cost of making `foo` and `bar` bigger by the size of an interface variable (which gets expensive if you have lots instances) *and* making zero values invalid.  :-/

Comment: The size of an interface variable is just a few bytes; if memory consumption is your top concern, you should focus on that at the expense of your design. But it would take many, many instances to have a significant impact, as an interface value adds only two words of overhead (16 bytes on a 64-bit system). Presumably your data structure eclipses that by far.

Comment: Oh: I have to take back my previous comment (but I won't delete it as Adrain's reply would otherwise lack context): I now see that the additional cost is just the size of pointer, not an interface value.  I "tsk" myself for inattentive reading.

Comment: @Adrian: in this case my actual `foo` objects are just 40 bytes (of which 7 are alignment padding), so adding another 16 is not insignificant.  Fortunately I have thought of a clever way to rearrange things, adding an interface value but with no net change in size in the most common case.