# Type Composition: overriding interface types

Tags: go, struct, interface, embedding, overriding

I want to compose a type of another type, but replace one of the fields (which is an interface value) with a fake. The problem I am getting is the underlying field is being used, so I can't seem to override the field.

I've demoed the problem here: https://play.golang.org/p/lHGnyjzIS-Y

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Printer interface {
    Print()
}

type PrinterService struct {}

func (ps PrinterService) Print() { fmt.Println("PrinterService") }

type Service struct {
    Client PrinterService
}

func (s Service) PrintViaMethod() { s.Client.Print() }

type FakeService struct {
    Service
    Client Printer
}

type SomeOtherService struct {}

func (sos SomeOtherService) Print() { fmt.Println("SomeOtherService") }

func main() {
    s := FakeService{Client: SomeOtherService{}}
    s.PrintViaMethod()
}
```

Why does it print `"PrinterService"`? I want it to print `"SomeOtherService"`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By `s.PrintViaMethod()`, you are calling the *promoted* method `FakeService.Service.PrintViaMethod()`, and the method receiver will be `FakeService.Service` which is of type `Service`, and `Service.PrintViaMethod()` calls `Service.Client.Print()`, where `Service.Client` is of type which `PrinterService`, that's why it prints `"PrinterService"`.

In Go there is [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), but there is no [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). When you embed a type in a struct, methods of the embedded type get promoted and will be part of the method set of the embedder type. But when such a promoted method is called, it will get the *embedded value* as the receiver, not the embedder.

To achieve what you want, you would have to "override" the `PrintViaMethod()` method by providing your implementation of it for the `FakeService` type (with `FakeService` receiver type), and inside it call `FakeService.Client.Print()`.

By doing so `s.PrintViaMethod()` will denote the `FakeService.PrintViaMethod()` method as that will be at the shallowest depth where the `PrintViaMethod()` exists (and not `FakeService.Service.PrintViaMethod()`). This is detailed in [Spec: Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors).

For example:

```
func (fs FakeService) PrintViaMethod() {
    fs.Client.Print()
}
```

Then the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HtOIfuq24ge)):

```
SomeOtherService
```

See related questions and answers with more details:

[Go embedded struct call child method instead parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390736/go-embedded-struct-call-child-method-instead-parent-method/29390981#29390981)

[Does fragile base class issue exist in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819033/does-fragile-base-class-issue-exist-in-go/41827686#41827686)

Answer (score 4):

> Why does it print 'PrinterService'? I want it to print 'SomeOtherService'.

Because that's what your code says to do.  `PrintViaMethod` calls `s.Client.Print()`, and `s.Client` is a (zero value) instance of `PrinterService`, which outputs `PrinterService`.

What you probably want is to call `s.Print()` in `main()`. I don't see any reason for your `PrintByMethod` function at all.

Comment: The reason for me adding `PrintViaMethod` is me trying to replicate an issue I am getting with mocking an AWS service client like it says [in the documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/cloudformation/cloudformationiface/interface.go#L17-L56). My code seemed too hard to put here so I tried to distill the problem. Perhaps I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: The problem I have is when I call `something.Client.InterfaceMethod()` it uses the correct client, but when I call `something.Method()`, which in turn calls via the client, the client seems to be nil. My theory was I wasn't overriding the client correctly.

Comment: There is no overriding in go at all. Why do you try to mock something in this way?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You're focused on your solution, rather than the problem. What is the problem to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

As per `Flimzy` you are calling print `s.Client.Print()` which is of type `PrinterService` implemented as receiver to `Print()` function printing `PrinterService`. You can also change type of `Client` `PrinterService` in `Service` struct to `Someother service`

```
package embedded

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Printer interface {
    Print()
}

type PrinterService struct{}

func (ps PrinterService) Print() { fmt.Println("PrinterService") }

type Service struct {
    Client SomeOtherService
}

func (s Service) PrintViaMethod() { s.Client.Print() }

type FakeService struct {
    Service
    Client Printer
}

type SomeOtherService struct{}

func (sos SomeOtherService) Print() { fmt.Println("SomeOtherService") }

func Call() {
    s := FakeService{Client: SomeOtherService{}}
    s.PrintViaMethod()
}
```